# How to store application data / resources in .net Applications

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, design-patterns

I have a .net forms application that I am currently writing in which I have a number of resources that my program uses. Some images, font files, scripts (my program calls octave scripts), etc..

Right now I have different folders that I manually create in the startup directory of my program and access them through Application.StartupPath. However this causes me the have to maintain a separate set of files for both the debug build and release build versions which has caused some nasty bugs in the past. I edited some octave scripts in debug months before and forgot to copy them over to the release scripts folder. Is there a better way to reference the resources?

Comment: Please explain this part `I have different folders that I manually create in the startup directory of my program and access them through Application.StartupPath`. I don't see anything wrong in having separate files for both debug and release. On the contrary, trying to consolidate Debug and Release files may cause you some nasty bugs.

Comment: I think Neolisk makes an excellent point. Sometimes you want different versions of the resources, however lots of times you don't need separate versions. But nothing keeps you from doing both, putting resources in a common directory when you don't need separate debug and release versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to store resources inside the program itself.
Access your project's Resources section [Project menu => "PROJECT NAME" Properties... => Resources(left side)], and add the files there.
You can also edit the resources by double-clicking on them.

In your code, you should have these resources available under the My namespace (My.Resources."RESOURCE NAME").

The resource's type (in code) depends on which kind of resource you add it as (See drop-down list at top-left corner):

- Images become System.Drawing.Bitmap
- Icons become System.Drawing.Icon
- Strings become System.String
- Text files become System.String
- Non-text files become an array, System.Byte()

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are building a windows app since you did not mention anything that made it sound like a web app. I would think that you should be able to put your resources into the resources directory which will link the resources into with you application when you build (you don't have to tag resource files as copy to output directory) as part of a .resx file. You can manage your resources by opening your project properties. For control with image properties, you can simply reference the image directly from .resx file, if you need to load custom resources into a form, try

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourresourcename.ext");
```

You may have to decorate the resource name with a path, an easy way to figure this out is to call

```
string[] resourcenames = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

You can get a little fancier and create multiple .resx files, often used for internationalization.

Comment: I wish I could select both answers as correct since both contained useful information. Thank you!